# After taking 13 pictures I accidentally open the back and it rewind to 1. please help!

Tags: film

how many shots do I have left and did I lose those 13 pictures? what should I do? I am using Pentax espio 160

Comment: I'm not familiar with the specific camera, but some auto winding film cameras fully extend the film and roll it back into the canister as you shoot. I think my old Pentax ZX-M did that. Does it wind for a long time when you put in a new roll? If so, the pictures you shot might have already been rolled into the canister (except about half of the last frame).

Answer (score 4):

If you rewound it whilst the back was open, you likely lost the whole lot.

The only way to know for certain is to get the roll developed.
Let the lab know what happened. If they're kind, they *might* do it for free if you killed the entire film. Some labs charge for results rather than effort; but it's a 'service' not a right.

Don't attempt to re-thread it in an effort to gain a few frames.

Comment: Even if they don't do free, at the very least, you can ask them not to make the prints if the roll's been ruined, so you might only have to pay for the processing. You'll want to go to a real photo lab instead of a one-hour place though.